# How to better reword this sentence? (cover letter writing question)

Tags: grammar, expressions, expression-choice

> I am confident my skills would benefit your company by allowing me to make original contributions to the research on Artificial Intelligence.

In fact, it is two sentences combined. I want to express:

> My skills would allow me to make original contributions to the research on Artificial Intelligence. 
>   My research would benefit your company.

The first sentence sounds odd. Is it correct from the view of a native speaker? Is there a better way to express my true meaning using one sentence?

Comment: The first is more fluent, providing that AI is a major interest of the job (and replacing "the" with "your"). Otherwise you could list you skills, breaking the "My skills . . ." sentence into two distinct points. The first would be your original thinking ability, the second your experience in the field of AI. It isn't quite clear if this is a covering letter, rather than the CV itself. If so, you could use both my ideas. But I suspect CV writing is off topic ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Skills" seems mundane when speaking of original AI research. Plumbers have "skills" but they're not expected to perform groundbreaking research.
There is no reason to capitalize artificial intelligence.

This might work better:
**I am confident the company would benefit from my contributions to original research in the field of artificial intelligence.**

Comment: Yeah... But the skills or the experience are the things I want to highlight. Is it better if I rewrite "I am confident my research experience in statistics would benefit your company by allowing me to make original contributions to the research on Artificial Intelligence." I specified the experience and not using the word "skills". (statistics is one the key tools to solve AI problems)